# jitify file not found

Tags: jit, cupy

I am absolutely new to python programming anf VS code. I want to do GPU programming and i installed CUDA toolkit, pip installed cupy and tried running gpu codes but i get this runtime error

**../__type_traits/remove_cv.h(19): warning: ../__type_traits/remove_volatile.h: [jitify] File not found**

what could be the reason for this?

I am not sure what to do. Is python and cuda and cupy all these different files installation and setting a simple working code this difficult to work? like im finding this suprememly difficult and almost wanna give up. Could you suggest some simpler follow along instructions which i can follow to set up a simple gpu program?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this error is the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77893287). It's been fixed and will be resolved by CuPy v13.1.0, as per the answer given there.